# Testing my website on IE7 and IE8 compatibilty view?

Tags: internet-explorer, web-applications, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have windows 7 and IE8. But i want to test my site on IE7 too. Is there a utility which i can install on windows and test my site on both version of IE. My Windows 7 also does not allow me to install IE7 saying IE7 is not valid for this OS.  Another question is if i run my site on compatibilty view , is it equivalent to run it on IE7?I am net getting how can i test my site on IE7  and IE8 on same machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compatibility view isn't completely equal to the real browser, but serves to see serious errors.

In Microsoft page can download IE6 and IE7, but you need a virtual machine (and image of Windows XP) for install that.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2